# Obtaining a table of solutions for a coupled set of equations

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to obtain a table of values for `s1` and `s2`, for different values of `m`. The equations for `s1` and `s2` depend on `N1` and `N2` that are also solutions to a system of equations that also depend on `m`. Here is my code so far:

```
d = 0.1;
bet = 0.001;
mu = 0.001;
fc1 = (2/8)^2;
fc2 = (3/8)^2;
N1p = N1*(1 - m) + N2*m;
N2p = N2*(1 - m) + N1*m;
b1 = 1 - bet*N1p - fc1;
b2 = 1 - bet*N2p - fc2;
b1mut = 1 - bet*N1;
b2mut = 1 - bet*N2;


equil = {N1, N2} /. Table[NSolve[{N1 == N1p*b1*2, 
 N2 == N2p*b2*2 && N1 > 0 && N2 > 0}, {N1, N2}, Reals], {m, 0, 1, 
0.1}]

fp = {s1, s2} /. Table[NSolve[{d + m*s2 + (1 - b1mut - d - m)*s1 +
   b1mut*s1^2 == s1, 
 d + m *s1 + (1 - b2mut - d - m)* s2 + b2mut*s2^2 == s2, 
 s1 < 1 && s2 < 1}, {s1, s2}, Reals], {m, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = 1/10;
bet = 1/1000;
mu = 1/1000;
fc1 = (2/8)^2;
fc2 = (3/8)^2;
N1p = N1*(1 - m) + N2*m;
N2p = N2*(1 - m) + N1*m;
b1 = 1 - bet*N1p - fc1;
b2 = 1 - bet*N2p - fc2;
b1mut = 1 - bet*N1;
b2mut = 1 - bet*N2;

eqns = {N1 == N1p*b1*2, N2 == N2p*b2*2 && N1 > 0 && N2 > 0, 
    d + m*s2 + (1 - b1mut - d - m)*s1 + b1mut*s1^2 == s1, 
    d + m*s1 + (1 - b2mut - d - m)*s2 + b2mut*s2^2 == s2, s1 < 1 && s2 < 1} //
    Simplify;

soln = Flatten /@ Transpose[{m -> # & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/10],
     Table[NSolve[eqns, {N1, N2, s1, s2}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 30][[1]], 
       {m, 0, 1, 1/10}]}];
```

Verifying solutions,

```
And @@ (And @@ eqns /. soln)

(*  True  *)

Join[{{m, s1, s2}}, {m, s1, s2} /. soln] // N // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
fms1 = Interpolation[{m, s1} /. soln];

fms2 = Interpolation[{m, s2} /. soln];

Plot[{fms1[m], fms2[m]}, {m, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{s1, s2}, {0.8, 0.8}]]
```

[image]